# jsf richfaces a4j:jsFunction forward outcome

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

Is it possible to create `a4j:jsFunction` that will call a method inside my managed bean and from there to perform forward to another jsf page ?

Thank's In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible because the `<a4j:jsFunction>` will create a javascript method available in the HTML that communicates with the server via Ajax. Instead, you could do something ugly like this:

```html
<h:form id="myForm">
    <a4j:jsFunction name="myJSFunction" action="#{myBean.jsLogic}"
        oncomplete="document.getElementById('myForm:btnForward').click();" />
    <a4j:commandButton id="btnForward" style="display: none;"
        action="#{myBean.doForward}" />
</h:form>
```

In this case at the end of your js function, you will call the method of a `<a4j:commandButton>` (also `<a4j:commandLink>` or any other `h` component) that could do the navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is not really a forward but you can do a redirect:

Just be sure that your corresponding `navigation-case` in `faces-config` file has the corresponding tag:

```
<redirect />
```

Then after the ajax call the browser will be redirected to the specified page.

This has the disadvantage in respect to Luiggi's response that makes two server calls, the ajax one and then the redirection.

As advantage, it makes cleaner code.